# Why my mail isnt sent though i configure smtp?

Tags: php, email

Code:

```
<?php
$to = "rock_tam@yahoo.com";
$subject = "Test mail";
$message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
$from = "krishna.tam04@gmail.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
echo "Mail Sent.";
?>
```

Error:

> Warning: mail() [function.mail]:
>   Failed to connect to mailserver at
>   "localhost" port 25, verify your
>   "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in
>   php.ini or use ini_set() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\mail.php on line 7
>   Mail Sent.

Comment: It has already been [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559898/xampp-mail-not-working-with-php-mail-function).

Answer (score 2):

Use SMTP server of your internet provider.