# php unable to receive mail through php mail function

Tags: php

i am new in php i want to send mail to user through php mail function i have write code but its not working mail is not receiving. i am testing it on localhost xamp server here is my code.

```
        <?php include "connection.php";

 if(isset($_POST) & !empty($_POST)){
//print_r($_POST); die;
   $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['username']);
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username = '$username'";
   $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
   $count = mysqli_num_rows($res);
   if($count == 1){
    echo "Send email to user with password";
   }else{
        echo "User name does not exist in database";
    }

   $r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
     $password = $r['password'];
   $to = $r['username'];
    $subject = "Your Recovered Password";

   $message = "Please use this password to login " . $password;
       $headers = "From :abc23@gmail.com";
      if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
        echo "Your Password has been sent to your email id";
       }else{
       echo "Failed to Recover your password, try again";

         } 

        }


     ?>
```

Comment: its not straight forward , checkout https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GnqRT7nh8wc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php xampp mail() function not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27273153/php-xampp-mail-function-not-working)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XAMPP mail not working with PHP mail() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559898/xampp-mail-not-working-with-php-mail-function)